# NSCoding: Custom Class unarchived, but with empty/nil class members

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscoding

I want to persist an NSDictionary, filled with custom Object to disc:

```
     NSDictionary *menuList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:xmlParser.items];
     //here the "Menu List"`s Object are filled correctly

     //persisting them to disc:
     NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:MENU_LIST_NAME];
     NSString *filePath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

     //saving using NSKeyedArchiver
     NSData* archiveData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:menuList];
     [archiveData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];

     //here the NSDictionary has the correct amount of Objects, but the Objects` class members are partially empty or nil
     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
     NSDictionary *theMenu = (NSDictionary*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Here the .m of the Custom Object (the kind of object stored in the NSDictionary)

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)tTitle level:(NSString*)tLevel state:(NSString*)tState visible:(BOOL)tVisible link:(NSString*)tLink linkType:(NSString*)tLinkType anId:(NSString*)tId {
if ((self = [super init])) {
    self.anId = tId;
    self.title = tTitle;
    self.level = tLevel;
    self.state = tState;
    self.visible = tVisible;
    self.link = tLink;
    self.linkType = tLinkType;
 }
 return self;
 }


 - (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
 [encoder encodeObject:self.anId forKey:@"anId"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.level forKey:@"level"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.state forKey:@"state"];
 [encoder encodeBool:self.visible forKey:@"visible"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.title forKey:@"title"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.link forKey:@"link"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.linkType forKey:@"linkType"];
 }

 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

 if(self == [super init]){
    self.anId = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"anId"];
    self.level = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"level"];
    self.state = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"state"];
    self.visible = [decoder decodeBoolForKey:@"visible"];
    self.title = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
    self.link = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"link"];
    self.linkType = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"linkType"];

}

return self;
 }
 @end
```

I dont know why the objects are unarchived correctly, but the object´s members are lost somewhere. I assume there must be an error somewhere in the NSCoding methods, but I just can´t find it, any help much appreciated.

Comment: Typo or really `if(self == [super init]){` ?

Comment: it´s from another example on that problem, you´re ok if you ignore it, I just removed it but the problem remains.

Comment: I think it´s solved, I changed the NSLibraryDirectory in the Path to NSDocumentDirectory, and now it works. Still love to accept an answer who can explain me why.

Comment: I did put some effort into looking up the differences between NSDocumentDirectory and NSLibraryDirectory but could not find any. That being said, your code is very lacking in terms of error checks - ex. you should pass NSError into that `NSData writeToFile` call.

Comment: it seems to not work anymore. Can´t explain why now. Problem is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

When you implement the `initWithCoder:` method, you need to call super properly:

```
if (self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]) {
```

The instance that is being unarchived has more attributes than just the additions in your specific class. You also don't want to be checking equality with `self`, you want to be assigning to `self`.

Comment: no, that is only the case if the super class implements the <NSCoding> protocol, which in my case, NSObject doesnt. I also thought it might be the solution and tried it, but it results in an NSInvalidArgumentException. Nevertheless you are right about the checking with self, which is completely wrong yes.